# Justify content in Bootstrap 4 is removed if I wrap the column in an anchor tag

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

If I am wrapping a columns in a anchor tag the justify-content-center class that I used is not working anymore.
I also tried to make a separate div inside the column and wrap that div in an anchor tag but still the justify-content-center class that I added to the row is not working which was working earlier when I didn't used the anchor tag.

You can see how in the right most column this is happening :
[image]

HTLM

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HomePage.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="logo-bar" style="height: 15vh;">

    </div>
    <nav class="my-nav py-0 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Search</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contribute</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Directory</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item"></li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item"></li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Benifits</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item"></li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">More</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item"></li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 "
                        src="324-3247438_best-messi-argentina-wallpaper-with-image-resolution-messi.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 " src="fc_barcelona_4.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 " src="Lionel-Messi-Wallpaper-Computer.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 " src="wp3266946.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- THE CODE FOR MAIN 3 CARDS -->
        <div class="row my-row ">
           
            <div class="col-lg-4  main-cards">
                <div class="row justify-content-around ">
                    <div class="col-lg-11  main-card-header
                    ">
                        <p>
                            <a href="">News and Updates</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-around">
                    <div class="col-lg-11 main-card-content shadow">

                        <p>date</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas debitis sequi reiciendis
                            hic corporis placeat fugiat unde ex? Quos ipsum ea suscipit vel reprehenderit fuga eos!
                            Delectus vero provident ducimus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 main-cards">
                <div class="row justify-content-around">
                    <div class="col-lg-11  main-card-header
                    ">
                        <p>
                            <a href="">Events</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row justify-content-around">
                    <div class="col-lg-11 main-card-content shadow">

                        <p>date</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas debitis sequi reiciendis
                            hic corporis placeat fugiat unde ex? Quos ipsum ea suscipit vel reprehenderit fuga eos!
                            Delectus vero provident ducimus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 main-cards">
                <div class="row justify-content-around">
                    <div class="col-lg-11  main-card-header
                    ">
                        <p>
                            <a href="">Sign in/Register</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row justify-content-around">
                    <a href="">
                    <div class="col-lg-11 main-card-content shadow" >
                        <p>date</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas debitis sequi reiciendis
                            hic corporis placeat fugiat unde ex? Quos ipsum ea suscipit vel reprehenderit fuga eos!
                            Delectus vero provident ducimus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>

        <div class="test"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap');
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0s;
}

body,html{
   height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid{
   position: relative;
   max-width: 100%;
}

img{
   height: 69vh;
   max-width: 100%;
}

.my-row{
   
   /* border:3px solid black; */
   position: absolute;
   top: 62vh;
   left:0;
   z-index:1;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   margin-left: 10.5vw;
   margin-right: 10.5vw;
   
   
}

.my-carousel{
   position: absolute;
   width:100%;
}


.main-cards{
   /* background-color:black; */
   border: 1px solid blue;
   /* opacity: 50%; */
   
}

.main-card-header{
   background-color:#F78222;
   height: 7.2vh;
   border-top-left-radius: 1vh;
   border-top-right-radius: 1vh;
   
   }
    
.main-card-header a{
       font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #FFFFFF;
       text-decoration: none;
       font-size: 2vh;
   }

.main-card-header p{
   margin-top: 1.5vh;
}

.main-card-content {
   /* background-color: black; */
   /* opacity: 50%; */
   border: 1px solid red;
   padding: 1rem 2rem;
   min-height: 22rem;

}

.shadow{
   box-shadow:0 0 20px -10px black ;

}

.test {

  
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your original code wasn’t doing what you wanted is because you had setup the row that contains your card with `justify-content-around,` which centers its content and then you created a column with `col-lg-11,` which sets its width to 91.67% of the parent (the row). The column in your other cards gets centered because its width is less than the row’s width. When you enclosed the column inside an anchor tag, the anchor tag became the thing that would be centered by the row’s `justify-content-around,` *but* the anchor tag, without any styling, is the same width as the row. That’s because children of a flex container are automatically set to `flex: 0 1 auto;` which is the same as `flex-grow: 0;   flex-shrink: 1;   flex-basis: auto;` The `flex-shrink: 1` tells the browser to shrink your anchor tag to fit the space, which is the full width of the row. Problem is, there’s nothing to center the column.

There are several ways to get the column content into the center.
You can put the anchor tag into the column and let the column center like the other cards.
You could style the anchor tag as `col-lg-11 main-card-content shadow` and change the existing column to just col.
Or, what hadn’t occurred to me before, is to center the column within the anchor tab using `mx-auto.` — `<div class="col-lg-11 main-card-content shadow mx-auto">`

For your revised requirement, having the entire card act as a link, that’s easier, since the card with a column aren’t setup as `display: flex` — you can wrap the content in an anchor tag, restyle the text, add a hover effect, and you’re done.

I switched the styling for the row for the cards from position absolute to using a negative margin to get it to partially cover the carousel (and I played with the styling for the sign-in card hover).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
        img {
        height: 69vh;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .my-row {

        /* border:3px solid black; */
        /* position: absolute;
        top: 62vh;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0; */
        margin-left: 10.5vw;
        margin-right: 10.5vw;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
        margin-top: -3.5rem;
    }

    .my-carousel {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }


    .main-cards {
        /* background-color:black; */
        border: 1px solid blue;
        /* opacity: 50%; */

    }

    .main-card-header {
        background-color: #F78222;
        height: 7.2vh;
        border-top-left-radius: 1vh;
        border-top-right-radius: 1vh;

    }

    .main-card-header a, .register-link p.register-header {
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 2vh;
    }

    .register-link, .register-link:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .register-link p {
        color: #212529;
    }

    .register-link:hover .sign-in {
        background-color: #910f41;
        transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
    }

    .register-link:hover p {
        color: #fff;
        transition: color 0.25s ease;
    }

    .main-card-header p {
        margin-top: 1.5vh;
    }

    .main-card-content {
        /* background-color: black; */
        /* opacity: 50%; */
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
        min-height: 22rem;
    }

    .shadow {
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px -10px black;
    }

    .test {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>

<div class="logo-bar" style="height: 15vh;">

</div>
<nav class="my-nav py-0 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Search</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contribute</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Directory</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Benifits</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">More</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100 " src="324-3247438_best-messi-argentina-wallpaper-with-image-resolution-messi.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100 " src="fc_barcelona_4.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100 " src="Lionel-Messi-Wallpaper-Computer.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100 " src="wp3266946.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- THE CODE FOR MAIN 3 CARDS -->
    <div class="row my-row ">
        <div class="col-lg-4  main-cards">
            <div class="row justify-content-around ">
                <div class="col-lg-11  main-card-header">
                    <p>
                        <a href="">News and Updates</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-around">
                <div class="col-lg-11 main-card-content shadow">
                    <p>date</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas debitis sequi reiciendis hic corporis placeat fugiat unde ex? Quos ipsum ea suscipit vel reprehenderit fuga eos! Delectus vero provident ducimus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 main-cards">
            <div class="row justify-content-around">
                <div class="col-lg-11  main-card-header">
                    <p>
                        <a href="">Events</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-around">
                <div class="col-lg-11 main-card-content shadow">
                    <p>date</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas debitis sequi reiciendis hic corporis placeat fugiat unde ex? Quos ipsum ea suscipit vel reprehenderit fuga eos! Delectus vero provident ducimus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 main-cards">
            <a class="register-link" href="#">
                <div class="row justify-content-around">
                    <div class="col-lg-11  main-card-header">
                        <p class="register-header">
                            Sign in/Register
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-around">
                    <div class="col-lg-11 main-card-content shadow sign-in">
                        <p>date</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas debitis sequi reiciendis hic corporis placeat fugiat unde ex? Quos ipsum ea suscipit vel reprehenderit fuga eos! Delectus vero provident ducimus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test" style="height: 100px;"></div>
```

Also, you had some extra  tags in your navbar that I’ve removed.

And it’s best to use the Stackoverflow snippet function to show what your code is doing, rather than just pasting your code into the question.

Comment: Hello, thank you for solving the problem, but can you please also explain why this was happening. Also I want the whole card to act as a clickable link, because we have made a separate div to be wrapped by the anchor tag only some area over the text is clickable, can you PLEASE solve this as well.

Comment: See if the revised answer does what you need.